# Get-CimInstance to list out printers on my computer in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list out all of the printers on my computer using Get-CimInstance. I tried to use the printerobject in powershell but i am getting an error when using it with the ciminstance. I get an error which says invalid class in powershell.

```
Get-CimInstance PrinterObject
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `Get-Printer` to list them?

Answer (score 0):

The class you're looking for is "Win32_Printer":

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Printer
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also try:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Printer -ComputerName "nameoftheprinterserver"
```